# python codeacademy A day at the supermarket def return

Tags: python

[image]

My work on Python course at Codeacademy but it threw an error. I am a newbie. So if anyone can help, please elaborate on it a little bit.
Thank you!

Comment: What error does it throw ? please post the code in the question and show us how to reproduce the error. Help us help you ;)

Comment: We're not going to be able to help you as the question is written -- your image does not include your error. Unless you mean "None" that just means your program isn't outputting anything. The code you have visible does nothing. You have to call your function and provide it with inputs. I doubt your function does what you think though. All it will do is add whatever value you give it to 0 and return it...which means you'll always get back whatever number you input.

Comment: Thanks guys. I will pay attention next time! Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screen shot, I am guessing the variable food is a dictionary containing food items as well as the price of each item. total is clearly a number which can either be an integer or a float.

In that case, you cannot add a number to a dictionary. that is why you are gettng the error.

What you should do is extract the price of a food item from the dictionary, then add said price to total. Ths can be achieved with a for loop. A simple example is as follows:

```
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for item in food:
        item_price = food[item]
        total = total + item_price
    return total
```

The item price is gotten from the dictionary keys.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that food is a list of strings.  You can iterate through the list with

```
for f in food
```

Then look of the price with

```
prices[f]
```

and add it to the total.

Your function will end up looking like this.

```
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for f in food:
        total = total + prices[f]
    return total
```

I am assuming that they are testing your code by running

```
compute_bill(shopping_list)
```

which returns 7.5

I hope this helps, next time please copy and past your code instead of taking a screen shot.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Cannot upvote your answer as I have not had enough "reputation" yet!